# Saving ListView into Properties.Settings.Default

Tags: c#, listview

I have build this C# for LOADING and SAVING items and subitems from a ListView:

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        this.Location=Properties.Settings.Default.FormLocation;
        if (Properties.Settings.Default.AllePcer == null) {
            Properties.Settings.Default.AllePcer = new StringCollection();
        }
        var items = new ListViewItem[Properties.Settings.Default.AllePcer.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < items.Length; i++) {
            items[i] = new ListViewItem(Properties.Settings.Default.AllePcer[i].Split('|'));
        }
        this.listView1.Items.AddRange(items);
        this.Show();
        butten_Help.Focus();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
        Properties.Settings.Default.FormLocation=this.Location;
        Properties.Settings.Default.AllePcer = new StringCollection();
        var items = new List<string>();
        foreach (ListViewItem item in this.listView1.Items) {
            List<string> subitems = new List<string>();
            foreach (ListViewItem.ListViewSubItem subitem in item.SubItems) {
                subitems.Add(subitem.Text);
            }
            items.Add(string.Join("|", subitems)); <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
        }
        Properties.Settings.Default.AllePcer.AddRange(items.ToArray());
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
```

The line with the "<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<" gives me compilingerror:

> cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to
>   'string[]'

How can I correct this ?

Comment: Add strings to your `items` list instead of a `List`

Comment: [string.Join][1]
accepts an `IEnumerable<T>` for the second parameter and returns a `string`. In your case, you are passing a `List<string>`, which implements this interface, so I see no reason why it would be complaining here. The fact it thinks it is an `array` is somewhat puzzling. Step through the code in the debugger and look at the types and values being set.

  [1]: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992421(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ... or just make the problematic line like this:

items.Add(string.Join("|", subitems.ToArray()));